# Chinese Idiom puzzle 6

Tags: idioms, games

Please solve the following puzzle

[image]

1. Simultaneously raise the Combat capability and reduce the number of soldiers of the army
2. When living is so painful, it is better off being dead
3. To fight a battle with a river behind the army (cut off their own retreat route, show determination)
4. Another name for 兵捉賊 game where children play the roles of soldiers and bandits chasing each other
5. Even grasses and trees seem like the enemy's soldiers. Describe nervousness 出處:《晋书·苻坚载记》
6. Stay Healthy
7. Send out the soldiers after the bandits have already gone
8. Describes that the army is defeated as a mountain collapsed
9. The military is an ominous instrument, virtuous rule use it only when there's no other choice 出自《道德经》
10. Travel the world, make where I go to my home
11. Formula
12. Saying that the same thing should not be done three times in a row
13. Four legs pointing at the sky (The appearance of falling on one's back)
14. Facing a big enemy
15. Die before the war is won 出自於杜甫的《蜀相》
16. Military action requires speed 《三國演義．第二六回》
17. The winner writes the history
18. Prison guard
19. Panic and make oneself unprepared to deal with the situation
20. Show leader quality
21. Employ risky Military action

A. Be attacked from two sides

B. Complete arduous and great affairs successfully

C. A man's ambition is the whole world (Describe lofty ambitions and ideals)

D. The general who lost a battle

E. War is dangerous

F. Victory and defeat are something that the Military men often encounter. ( Metaphor things can't always be successful)

G. Send troops to fight, encounter difficulties or be frustrated and cannot go smoothly

H. Metaphor for slight movements and changes)

I. Before the army can move, the supply has to be sent first

J. Still a hero even in defeat

K. Allergic words, the next part is 多多益善

L. Original work

M. Beyond the world, becoming a god (describe a god-like level of skill)

N. A commander personally leads his soldiers into battle

O. The soldiers are the bandits

P. Deception is a norm in military strategy 語本《韓非子．難一》

Q. Another word for 自殺

R. A chaotic war situation

S. Time does not wait for us. Metaphor missed the opportunity and regrets it.《文選．嵇康．幽憤詩》

T. Maintain an army for the day when war comes

U. Stepping stone

V. Escape from death

More hints below

> [image]

Answer (score 1):

> [image]

Kinda hard to be honest. I had to use the internet for some of them. Note that for L, 著 and 着 are separate in simplified Chinese and are combined into 著 in traditional （着 is considered a variant of 著）. In L, it’s pronounced yuán zhù 原著, but in 21, it’s pronounced bīng xíng xiǎn zhāo 兵行险着

Pardon my handwriting. I did this on my phone.

Comment: Good job, You got most of them. But 1. B. H. J. M. U are incorrect please see my answer

Answer (score 0):

A：腹背受敌
17:成王败寇
D：败军之将
20： 大将之风 （i don't think this is a 成语，but this is the most close one）
14:大敌当前
G：出师不利
3：背水一战
21：兵行险招

Feel like doing homework..

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for playing

Here is the answer:

> [image]